# ObjC-Why it is incorrect when implement [alloc] and [init] methods separatly?

Tags: objective-c, init, alloc

Never initialize an object without reassigning any pointer to that object. As an example, don’t do this:

```
NSObject *someObject = [NSObject alloc];
[someObject init];
```

If the call to init returns some other object, you’ll be left with a pointer to the object that was originally allocated but never initialized.

Actually, this is a example in Apple's ObjC document, but i'm not quite clear with this, that is, why `NSObject *someObject = [[NSObject alloc] init]` can promise return the object we just needed, while `NSObject *someObject = [NSObject alloc]; [someObject init];` can not?

Comment: Whenever I need to do [[.... alloc]init], I prefer [... new]. Saves typing and code looks smaller. If you need to do initWith... then no other option.

Comment: en, [[... alloc] init] is equivalent to [... new], if you just need a init-only object, which set the instance variables values to 0 if there is any.

Answer (score 3):

Just because -init could return something different from someObject. In your example you have to re-assign the pointer to the result of the -init.

Comment: But when and how it can return something different from someObject? And how to reassign the pointer to the result of the -init in that alloc init separated version?

Comment: i have already known the answer of this issue, what a stupid question ...